# NameError: name 'coleccion' is not defined (lista)

Tags: python-3.x, clase

Muy buenas caballeros vengo a formular unas preguntas respecto a un script que estoy creando, primero que todo como observan en el script hice una clase que remplaza ciertos caracteres por otros con instrucciones especiales para cada carácter, el caso es que hice un método de guardado de las listas generadas pero al llamar al método de la clase me salta un error, no encuentro el error por el cual no me crea el fichero con el contenido generado.

El siguiente inconveniente es que la segunda entrada tiene unas condiciones las cuales son mostrarse en forma de "lower" o "upper" definidas al llamar a la clase Wordlist() el problema es que debe recibir otra condición "azar" en la cual el programa elige por si mismo si quiere mostrar la segunda entrada en upper u lower.

Seria de gran ayuda si me brindan una solución y consejos acerca de estos errores y como evitarlos, y si tiene mejores formas de como mejorar el script es mas que bienvenido.

```
import sys 
import random
from listas import *
from io import open


class Wordlist():

    def __init__(self, entrada1, entrada2, entrada3, entrada4, cantidad, modo, archivo ): 
        self.entrada1 = entrada1
        self.entrada2 = entrada2
        self.entrada3 = entrada3
        self.entrada4 = entrada4
        self.cantidad = cantidad
        self.modo = modo
        self.archivo = archivo

    def generar(self):

        for r in range(int(self.cantidad)):

            try:
                coleccion = [self.entrada1]  # lista donde se alojan todos los parametros reemplazados

                caracter2 = self.entrada2.replace("@",random.choice(letras))                
                if self.modo == "upper":
                    coleccion.append(caracter2.upper())
                elif self.modo == "lower":
                    coleccion.append(caracter2.lower())
                elif self.modo == "azar":              #condicion donde al ingresar la palabra "azar" el programa elige por el usuario en que modo mostrar "upper" o "lower"
                    pass
                else:
                    print("Error! comando desconocido")

                caracter3 = self.entrada3.replace("$",random.choice(numeros))
                coleccion.append(caracter3)

                caracter4 = self.entrada4.replace("!",random.choice(especiales))
                coleccion.append(caracter4)
                print("".join(coleccion))
                self.guardar()

            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error {e}")

    def guardar(self):                              #metodo de guardado en cual me debe crear un 
        with open(self.archivo,'w') as fichero:       #fichero y agregar la lista llamada coleccion 
            fichero.write(coleccion)
            print("Creando fichero....")

g = Wordlist('Contraseña', '@','$','!', 4, "lower", "lista.txt")
g.generar()
```

Answer (score 0):

La variable `colección` es una variable local del método `generar`, en cuanto éste retorne dejará de existir y no puede ser accedida desde fuera. En el método `guardar` no existe por tanto esta variable. Tienes varias opciones, las más simples:

- Pasar `coleccion` al método `guardar` como argumento:

  ```
  def generar(self):
      # ....
      self.guardar(coleccion)

  def guardar(self, coleccion):
      # ...
  ```
- Hacer que `coleccion` sea un atributo de instancia y por tanto accesible desde cualquier método de instancia:

  ```
  def __init__(self, entrada1, entrada2, entrada3, entrada4, cantidad, modo, archivo ): 
      # ...
      self.coleccion = None

  def generar(self):
      # ....
      self.coleccion = [...]
      self.coleccion.append(...)
      self.guardar()

  def guardar(self):
      # ....
      fichero.write(self.coleccion)
  ```

Para que el programa elija aleatoriamente si usar `str.upper` o `str.lower` puedes elegir el método aleatoriamente:

```
coleccion.append(random.choice((caracter2.upper, caracter2.lower))())
```

Comment: funciona pero solo me escribe un linea de texto y no las que yo genero previamente

Comment: Usa el modo "a" para abrir el archivo, "w" lo trunca antes de escribir...

Comment: o ya veo, gracias man